# How to get location suggestions when i type any keyword in autocomplete text view

Tags: android, google-maps

I want get location(all over the world) suggestions in autocomplete textview as soon as i type keywords in it. Is there any api for it?
If it is there please provide me details or any sample code. If there is any service at google maps end regarding same please provide me details with all parameters i need to include in it.

Answer (score 0):

this api will solve your problem  https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete

Comment: how to create browser key . It says something like this. Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites)

One URL or pattern per line. Example: *.example.com/*